# Trazer os cinco último em uma linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma tabela de eventos. E cada PDV, é realizado um evento, com o ID do Evento, Data, Usuario e Tipo. Bem, sempre que eu faço uma consulta, eu populo um grid de evento. Gostaria de saber, como trazer os cinco últimos com LINQ e/ou Lambda, para um mesmo CNPJ?

Está correto esse código?

```
var result_evento = (from ev in db.T_CRM_Evento
                                 select new { ev.ID_CRM_Evento, ev.DE_Usuario, ev.ID_TipoEvento, ev.DT_Inclusao})
                                 .Take(5)
                                 .Max(evento => evento.DT_Inclusao);
```

Esse linq funcionou. Mexeu com meu layout, mas deyu certo. Pelo menos em termos de resultado do banco, funcionou.

```
 var result_evento = (from ev in db.T_CRM_Evento
                         .Where(e => e.DE_CNPJ == carregagrid.Cnpj)
                                     select new { ev.ID_CRM_Evento, ev.DE_Usuario, ev.ID_TipoEvento, ev.DT_Inclusao })
                                     .Take(5)
                                     .OrderByDescending(dt => dt.DT_Inclusao);
```

Comment: Cadê o parâmetro do CNPJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou achando muito estranho o linq acima não ter funcionado, de qualquer forma, faça isso

```
var result_evento = (from ev in db.T_CRM_Evento
                         where ev.DE_CNPJ == carregagrid.Cnpj
                         select new {
                            ev.ID_CRM_Evento, 
                            ev.DE_Usuario, 
                            ev.ID_TipoEvento, 
                            ev.DT_Inclusao 
                         }).Take(5).OrderByDescending(dt => dt.DT_Inclusao);
```

Espero realmente que tenha funcionado, por que de acordo com suas descrições, este código basta, se possível, envie sua view ou onde você está mostrando os resultados, talvez seja em outro lugar o problema.

Comment: Mas eu já fiz. Conforme disse, já foi resolvido.

Comment: Opa, então me desculpe :X - Boa sorte com o projeto.

Comment: Valeu cara, como sua resposta foi a mesma que a minha e para não da nenhuma resposta igual, vou marcar a sua com válida.

Comment: A pergunta parece já ter sido respondida entao deixo uma dica : Quando tiver uma dúvida com linq sugiro usar o LINQER, ele converte SQL pra LINQ. Muito útil. Se tiver Reshaper ele pode sugerir uma lambda pra vc.